# WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'primeng/inputtext' in output.globals – guessing 'inputtext'

Tags: angular, angular-cli, primeng, angular11, ng-packagr

I am using following versions
Angular CLI: 11.0.7
Node: 10.24.1
primeng : 11.4.3

I using primeng with in angular library project, But get some warnings when I compile library

```
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'primeng/inputtext' in output.globals – guessing 'inputtext'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'primeng/button' in output.globals – guessing 'button'
WARNING: No name was provided for external module 'primeng/table' in output.globals – guessing 'table'
```

even after adding moduleIds in ng-package.json

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/discover-search-lib",
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/public-api.ts",
    "umdModuleIds": {
      "primeng/inputtext": "inputtext",
      "primeng/table": "table",
      "primeng/button": "button"
    }
  }
}
```

And what is the best way to add all components of primeng in umdModuleIds so that ng-packagr recognizes it ?

Comment: did you figure this out? i am at the exact same stage right now.